# Cloudwatch agent keep files open

Tags: windows, logging, windows-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

When I'am using a cloudwatch agent service to monitoring a application log, this file it is keep in using by cloudwatch agent. If my application it is restarted, it can't write in log file, because the file are keeping open by cloudwatch service.

Someone will can help?

Any help will be appreciated.